# Can't find "rackup" command?

Tags: ruby, sinatra, rackup

http://titusd.co.uk/2010/04/07/a-beginners-sinatra-tutorial

I was trying to run `rackup config.ru` from the command line as instructed in the tutorial above in section 4. It ended up saying "No command 'rackup' found".

Any idea what happened?

Comment: I guess you installed rack with bundle with an unusual `--binstubs` dir, if so try `bundle help exec` and read how it works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `rackup1.8 config.ru` instead of `rackup config.ru` solved my problem. But I am not terribly sure what happened, though.

Comment: "rackup1.8" looks like the name the installer would have given Ruby and its auxiliary apps to avoid name collisions in case you wanted to install Ruby 1.9 in parallel. Ruby would have been Ruby1.8 and Ruby1.9 respectively.

Answer (score 1):

A bit late to the party, however I came across this using Sinatra at a hack night and our fix was to use the true relative path in config.ru:

```
require './app'
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you didn't mention the version of Rack you used, it seems like you were using the old version.

Just:

```
rackup
```

will do the thing.